# Download Infopath Attachment into harddrive with VBA

Tags: xml, vba, infopath

I have about 1000 xml infopath document that contains attachments in it. I'm looking for a way to download the infopath attachments into my drive through VBA, but I couldn't find any lead on this. Any code or tutorial will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean 'download'?  From the web?  Try this.

```
Sub Test()
 Dim FileNum As Long
 Dim FileData() As Byte
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim WHTTP As Object

 On Error Resume Next
 Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
 End If
 On Error GoTo 0

 MyFile = "website xxxx.com"

 WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
 WHTTP.Send here is where I stop. This is the error message:
 "Run-time error '-2147012867 (80072efd)':
A connection with the server could not be established"
 FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
 Set WHTTP = Nothing

 If Dir("c:\test", vbDirectory) = Empty Then MkDir "c:\test"

 FileNum = FreeFile
 Open "the file I downloaded " For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
 Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
 Close #FileNum

 MsgBox "Open the folder [ c:\test] for the downloaded file..."
 End Sub
```

Also, take a look at this.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd0ee306-7bb5-4ce4-8341-edd9475f84ad/excel-2007-use-vba-to-download-save-csv-from-url